# What is map[(int)x]++;What it does?

Tags: java, algorithm

Hey I took part in Facebook Hacker Competition and I got a solution of this question.
I solved th question in order O(K^2) but this guy solved it in O(^K).
Please explain me what the code doing.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Scanner;

     public class FindTheMin {

private long getNextMin(long[] map, long start, long k) {
    while (map[(int)(start)] > 0)
        start++;
    return start;
}

public long findNth(long n, long k, long a, long b, long c, long r) {
    long[] cache = new long[100010];
    long[] map = new long[100010];
    long pre = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        long num;
        if (i == 0)
            num = a;
        else
            num = (b * pre + c) % r;
        cache[i] = num;
        if (num <= k + 1)
            map[(int) num]++;
        pre = num;
    }

    pre = getNextMin(map, 0, k);
    cache[(int)k] = pre;
    map[(int)pre]++;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (int)k; i++) {
        long deque = cache[i];
        if (deque > k) {
            long x = getNextMin(map, pre, k);
            cache[i] = x;
            map[(int)x]++;
            pre = x;
        } else {
            if (deque < pre) {
                if(map[(int)deque] == 1) {
                    cache[i] = deque;
                    pre = deque;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            map[(int)deque]--;
            long x = getNextMin(map, pre, k);
            cache[i] = x;
            pre = x;
            map[(int)x]++;
        }
    }

    return cache[(int)((n - 1) % (k + 1))];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("in.txt"));
        int m = s.nextInt();
        FindTheMin f = new FindTheMin();

        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            int n, k, a, b, c, r;
            n = s.nextInt();
            k = s.nextInt();
            a = s.nextInt();
            b = s.nextInt();
            c = s.nextInt();
            r = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + f.findNth(n, k, a, b, c, r));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

And what are the best ways to learn things like this. the best way to learn java?
This was the question
https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=494433657264959&round=185564241586420

Comment: what do you mean by **O(^K)** ?

Comment: Could you please post the question for these of us who prefer to not have facebook accounts?

Comment: `map[(int)pre]++` means retrieve the value at `map[int(x)]` first and then increments the value obtained by 1.

Comment: I don't believe you solved it if you're asking what his solution is doing.

Comment: Is there a place to read the competition question without having to have a facebook account?

Answer (score 2):

`map[(int)x]++` does the same as the following:

```
int index = (int) x;
map[index]++;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know `what the code doing`.This is only part of the whole logic.To be honest this code is black box to me...

Comment: @Cratylus: you're probably right, but that is the only clear question the guy asked so I figured I'd at least answer it

Comment: is this really worth a down-vote? I am answering part of the OP's question accurately, how is your response to that a down-vote?

Comment: Its easier if one would know the question, posted here

Comment: @Cratylus, the OP knows what the code is doing because he read and participated in the facebook task, He wants to knwo how the code works.

Comment: @AlexWien:Yes, this what I am saying also.

Comment: @Cratylus: heh yeah I figured, I was asking the person who did, though. no worries

Comment: downvote 'cause i don't understand the upvote.. jk i didn't vote, just saw some fun comments and thought i'd chime in...

Answer (score 1):

What is `map[(int)x]++;`What it does?

arrays in java accepts only an integer index, but x in your code is a long value.
therefore it has to be casted to int:

This code gets element at index x from array map and adds 1 to the value:

same as:

```
map[ix]++;  // where ix = (int) x;
```

Question 2: 
And what are the best ways to learn things like this. the best way to learn java?

Buy, read and understand:

```
Robert Sedgewick, Algorithms Fourth Edition
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
long x = getNextMin(map, pre, k);
cache[i] = x;
map[(int)x]++;
```

While `x` is a long, the indexes of an array may only be int. Furthermore, and more importantly, although `getNextMin` is returning a `long`, the programmer knows the value is actually an `int` (i.e. `x <= Integer.MAX_VALUE`) otherwise there could be possible overflow resulting in a negative value for `x` which would cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception.

Now because java is statically typed, although the value returned by `getNextMin` fits into an `int`, you still must tell the compiler your intention to use it as an `int`; otherwise the compiler will assume it's a `long`. That is why you see `(int)x` -- since array indices must be of type `int`

For the code itself

```
map[(int)x]++;
```

could be written as

```
map[(int)x] =  map[(int)x] + 1;
```

or as

```
int y = (int) x
map[y]++; // or as map[y] = map[y] + 1
```

Again, if the value returned by `getNextMin` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the code will throw an exception. And so it may be a design flaw that the programmer is not handling the potential exception.